# html input[type=number] localization problems with chrome

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome, localization

I have a formular that gets 'translated' via javascript. The change of the language might include a change of the decimal separator as well. Because of that I set the `lang` attribute of the html-root and all `input type="number"` elements to the two-letter-language code of the language.

Everything works fine in Firefox. The decimal separators are swapped automatically.

But not in Chrome. Chrome seems to be ignoring the lang attribute, or, more specifically, the runtime change with javascript.

Example HTML below. The language is set to german in the input element, the decimal separator should be a *colon*. Swap the language to english with the links below, the decimal separator should change to *dot*:

```html
<form action="javascript: void(0);">
  <input type="number" id="x" step="0.1" lang="de" value="1.5" />
</form>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('x').lang='en';">[en]</a>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('x').lang='de';">[de]</a>
```

*I can't use external libraries in this project*, so the only way to solve this seems to use `input[type=text]` instead of `input[type=number]` and do validation and stuff like that manually... Any ideas?

And just for my curiosity, which one is 'wrong'? Does firefox more then it should (listening for changes of the lang-attribute) or is chrome missing something?

**EDIT**
It wouldn't solve my problem, but if jQuery could deal with this, tell me :)

Comment: What are the languages you need to depend on for this ?

Comment: @VigneshRaja I dont know. Currently its just english and german, but I think that spanish will be on my list in the near future too... Why? Do you think the problem is language dependent?

Comment: No. Its not language dependent. It will not work in latest versions of chrome. So I thought to device a js. As specified [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator), the decimal separator will become language dependent.

Comment: @VigneshRaja I am really sorry, but I dont understand what you want to tell me :/

Comment: I need to write a script that manipulates the input value based on the language attribute. So now it becomes language dependent. Because the decimals are specified in different formats in different lang. refer the above link.

Comment: @VigneshRaja Yes, but thats only possible for `input[type=text]`, not for `input[type=number]`. `input[type=number]` only takes values *with a dot* as separator, but it might *display* a colon dependent on the given language id. And besides of that, this is exactly what i've written in my question in the second last paragraph: *use textfields instead of numberfields and do validation and stuff like that manually*. I want to know if there is a way to fix the behavior of chrome since number fields are easier to use on mobile devices...